# How to apply XSLT to embedded XML in another XML

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

given the following XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
  <report>
    <![CDATA[<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><whatever><title>GREETING</title><greeting>Hi</greeting><name>Dave</name></whatever>]]>
  </report>
</root>
```

How can I use XSL-T to take into account this "embedded" XML?

An example output I would want to get after XSL-Transformations is like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<TransformedRoot>
  <data><html><head><title>GREETING</title></head><body><p>Hi, Dave!</p></body></html>
</TransformedRoot>
```

Assuming this is the standard XSL-T I am using:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:transform version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/root">
        <TransformedRoot>
           <data><!-- How do I get the elements here? --></data>
        </TransformedRoot>            
    </xsl:template>
```

Comment: Which XSLT 2.0 processor are you using? Saxon has http://saxonica.com/documentation9.4-demo/html/extensions/functions/parse.html so you can use `<xsl:template match="report"><xsl:apply-templates select="saxon:parse(normalize-space())"/></xsl:template>` and then you add templates for the elements in your embedded XML.

Comment: Would this also work if I have escaped XML like: <report>&lt;xml ... &gt;</report>

Comment: Yes, of course, whether you use a `CDATA` section or entity references, there is no difference in the data model XSLT works with, the content of the `report` element is a string with XML in both cases. That string needs to be parsed.

Comment: Okay, my next question is how I would fit the main XSL-T together with the XSL-T that I want to use for the embedded XML. I could copy paste them into the same file if needed, but how would I position them? XSL-T is not my forte, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With commercial editions of Saxon 9:

```
<xsl:transform version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:saxon="http://saxon.sf.net/">
<xsl:output method="xml" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/root">
        <TransformedRoot>
           <data>
             <xsl:apply-templates/>
           </data>
        </TransformedRoot>            
    </xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="report">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="saxon:parse(normalize-space(.))/node()"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="whatever">
  <html>
     <head>
        <xsl:copy-of select="title"/>
      </head>
      <body>
        <p>
         <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </p>
      </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="greeting">
  <xsl:value-of select="concat(., ', ')"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="name">
  <xsl:value-of select="concat(., '!')"/>
</xsl:template>
```