# How to convert soap response containing CDATA to new formatted xml using xslt?

Tags: xslt, soap, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0, cdata

I want to convert below code to some formatted xml code,

Input For XSLT Transformation:

```
<soap:Envelope
    xmlns:soap='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'>
    <soap:Body>
        <rejectQuoteXMLResponse
            xmlns='http://xxx.group.com'>
            <out>
                <![CDATA[

                    <TFGCPLResultXMLDO>
                        <processInstanceName>reejectQuoteXML</processInstanceName>
                        <duration>0</duration>
                        <accumulatedNumberOfExceptions>0</accumulatedNumberOfExceptions>
                        <accumulatedNumberOfErrors>0</accumulatedNumberOfErrors>
                        <accumulatedNumberOfWarnings>0</accumulatedNumberOfWarnings>
                        <numOfExceptions>0</numOfExceptions>
                        <numOfErrors>0</numOfErrors>
                        <numOfWarnings>0</numOfWarnings>
                        <BusinessMessages>
                            <BusinessErrors/>
                            <BusinessWarnings/>
                            <BusinessGenericMessages/>
                        </BusinessMessages>
                        <requestedTransSuccessfulInd>true</requestedTransSuccessfulInd>
                        <modifySuccessfulInd>false</modifySuccessfulInd>
                        <copySuccessfulInd>false</copySuccessfulInd>
                        <responseXMLString>
                            <RejectPolicyRes>
                                <status>Success</status>
                                <message>Reject Policy successful</message>
                            </RejectPolicyRes>
                        </responseXMLString>
                    </TFGCPLResultXMLDO>
                ]]>
            </out>
        </rejectQuoteXMLResponse>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Required Output:

```
<QuoteRejectRs>
    <UserId>344758</UserId>
    <QuoteDetails>
        <QuoteNumber>PA-Q450000</QuoteNumber>
        <Status>Success</Status>
        <Message>Reject Policy successful</Message>
    </QuoteDetails>
</QuoteRejectRs>
```

XSLT Transformation code:

```
<!-- <xsl:stylesheet
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
xmlns:md1="http://http://xxx.group.com" xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common" 
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs md1"
    extension-element-prefixes="exsl"
    version="2.0"> -->
<xsl:stylesheet
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <!--XML Response for Quote Reject which tell request has been submitted with success or fail -->
        <QuoteRejectRs>
            <UserId></UserId>
            <QuoteDetails>
                <QuoteNumber></QuoteNumber>
                <Status>
                    <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(substring-after(.,'Envelope/Body/TFGCPLResultXMLDO&gt;'), '&lt;Envelope/Body/TFGCPLResultXMLDO/responseXMLString/RejectPolicyRes/status')"/>
                </Status>
                <Message>
                    <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(substring-after(.,'Envelope/Body/TFGCPLResultXMLDO&gt;'), '&lt;Envelope/Body/TFGCPLResultXMLDO/responseXMLString/RejectPolicyRes/message')"/>
                </Message>
                <!--  <Status><xsl:value-of select="soap:Envelope/soap:Body/md1:rejectQuoteXMLResponse/md1:out/md1:status"/></Status><Message><xsl:value-of select="Envelope/Body/TFGCPLResultXMLDO/responseXMLString/RejectPolicyRes/message"/></Message>-->
            </QuoteDetails>
        </QuoteRejectRs>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I have tried and able to convert xml which contains namespace (soap:xxx) , but unable to convert xml which contains CDATA.

I have tried but getting  response containing &lt; &gt; format.

So anyone know solution for such task.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19424808/2402272

Comment: So which XSLT 2.0 processor do you use? Perhaps you can move to Saxon 9.8 which in all editions supports https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-31/#func-parse-xml.

Comment: I am using xslt2.0 version

Answer (score 0):

You complain that you are

> getting response containing &lt; &gt; format.

That's easy enough to fix.  `xsl:value-of` has an attribute `disable-output-escaping` specifically for that purpose, so something like

```
            <Status>
                <xsl:value-of
                    select="substring-before(substring-after(.,'Envelope/Body/TFGCPLResultXMLDO&gt;'), '&lt;Envelope/Body/TFGCPLResultXMLDO/responseXMLString/RejectPolicyRes/status')"
                    disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
            </Status>
            <Message>
                <xsl:value-of
                    select="substring-before(substring-after(.,'Envelope/Body/TFGCPLResultXMLDO&gt;'), '&lt;Envelope/Body/TFGCPLResultXMLDO/responseXMLString/RejectPolicyRes/message')"
                    disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
            </Message>
```

ought to do the job you seem to be looking for.

HOWEVER, I urge you to take a different approach.  Picking apart and parsing XML text via string functions is bad news.  What you really should do is parse the embedded XML as an XML document, and transform *that*.  Unfortunately, XSLT 1.0 and 2.0 do not have a standard mechanism for that, but some implementations add that as an extension, and depending on how you are performing the transformation, it may be comparatively easy to install your own extension function for the purpose.  Alternatively, you could extract the embedded XML as a preliminary step, and then transform just that.